# How are the carry and aux carry calculated for bitwise operations in the 8080

Tags: intel-8080

I am currently writing an 8080 emulator and am confused on why the carry flag is marked as "modified" in opcode lists such as

https://pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html
or 
http://www.emulator101.com/8080-by-opcode.html

is it just set to 0 or is there an actual way to calculate carry for a bitwise operation? I'm a bit confused as Pastraiser says it's modified and not just set to 0.

Comment: It's a modifier not modified.

Answer (score 0):

The [Intel 8080 Assembly Language Programming Manual](https://altairclone.com/downloads/manuals/8080%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf) is the authoritative source on questions like this. It has detailed descriptions for each instruction. For bitwise logical operations, it says the Carry flag is reset (i.e. set to 0):

> ## `ANA` Logical and (sic!) Register or Memory WIith Accumulator
>
> [...]
>
> The specified byte is logically `AND`ed bit
> by bit with the contents of the accumulator. The Carry bit
> is reset to zero

And similarly for `XRA` and `ORA`.